# ORM [object relation mapper ] on symfony

Tags: symfony

I know that doctrine is the default orm used by symfony , but i want to know is there is others orm that symfony 2 use?? 
thank you for your responses.

Comment: Propel is quite common: https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle.  I would imagine you could find a bundle wrapper for just about any of the orm's out there.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony integrates with Doctrine2 by default. I don't know of any other existing database abstraction bundles, but you can probably write your own if need comes.